# In github not able to enter the ssh key after pressing add ssh keys button

Tags: git, github

I have logged into my account using github . I am using cent os in my local system . I followed below link for the authentication with git and github
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
The problem is I have my id_rsa,id_rsa.pub keys but when I click on the "add ssh keys" button through github account no text box is prompting me to enter the key I am returning the same screen.

How should I go about , Anyone please help me in crossing this hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

1.
The field for entering the ssh key appears at the bottom of the list of your SSH keys, make sure you have scrolled down.

2.
If you have access to the internet on another device, you could send your id_rsa.pub to that device and try it on another browser.